# iOS local notification without turning on screen

Tags: ios, xamarin, notifications, uilocalnotification, wakeup

I'm working on app that will manage quite a lot of local notifications. So since I don't want to waste user's battery, I'm wondering - is there any possibility to don't turn on the screen? So the notification still will be fired and the banner will be on the screen but only if user will unlock the phone. It's kind of "minor notification" that are still should be displayed but they're not so important to wake up the phone.

And if there's such possibility - wouldn't it be what Apple calls "bad user experience". You know, kind of confusion that notification didn't wake up the phone's screen?

And yes, sound still should exist, because it should work as reminder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to say no, because you only get three options (badge, sound, alert). I guess it would be a "bad user experience" because if I hear a sound, I look at my phone to see if it's mine, and if the screen's not on, I assume it was someone else's phone.